# Question to find distance at which 2 trains will pass each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I was solving some questions related to motion, and I came through a question which I cant understand. The question goes like this:

> Two trains A and B, 100 km apart are approaching towards each other
>   with starting speed of $50km/h$. The train A is accelerating at
>   $18hm/h^2$. The distance where the engines cross each other from
>   starting point of A is: ?

I cant solve it. Can someone please help me find the solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Srry @JohnRennie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may assume the origin to be at the the starting point of train A. Then find the time after which the two trains meet. Finally you can find the displacement of train A using the equation of motion $$S= vt + \frac{1}{2}at^2$$.

Comment: I tried to find the time, but a quadratic equation with no integral root is formed. Can you help me?

Comment: post here, whatever you worked out

Comment: and anyways why do want the answer to be an integer....it can be anything!!!

Comment: see.... For Train 1, $s=ut+1/2at^2$ =  $s = 50t+9t^2$

Comment: and for Train 2, $s = 50t$

Comment: Now S of Train 1 + S of Train 2 should be 100... So $50t+50t+9t^2=100$..... $100t+9t^2=100$

Comment: Can you help me ahead of this?... Anyways thanks a lot